# Getting an error while creating stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, ssms

When I tried to create the following procedure, I get an error that the must declare scalar variable username.

How do I resolve this error?

```
Create procedure sp_addagent
     @username varchar(50),
     @password varchar(50),
     @contactno int
as

Begin
Set NOCOUNT ON
declare @usertype int=2
Insert into tbl_userlogin Values
(
    @username,
    @password,
    @contactno,
    @usertype
)
END
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to the DBA StackExchange. I answered the question based on the tag `mysql`, The code in your question looks like T-SQL. If the you meant SQL Server, please put the tag `sql-server` or `t-sql` or both

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this in MySQL

```
DELIMITER $$
Drop procedure if exists sp_addagent $$
Create procedure sp_addagent
(
     given_username varchar(50),
     given_password varchar(50),
     given_contactno int
)
BEGIN
SET @usertype = 2;
Insert into tbl_userlogin Values
(
    given_username,
    given_password,
    given_contactno,
    @usertype
);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```